# Converting assembly instructions to binary using objdump or gcc -c

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, x86, buffer-overflow

I'm working on the buffer bomb lab and I'm stuck on one thing.  I've written my exploit code to solve level 2 (firecracker) but I'm not sure how I can convert this to its raw form using `gcc -c`.
I've never written a compile-able assembly file but I have written instructions themselves and traced already written ones.. So I know how they work but I'm not sure how to syntactically write the code file itself.

Here are the current contents of the file I'm trying to convert to its raw form:

```
movl $0x1a4bb386, 0x804d200
push $0x0804915f 
ret
```

What do I need to add to this so that it will compile using `gcc -c` or `objdump -d`?
I need to figure out how many bytes these instructions take up and how to insert them into the buffer so that I can write my buffer overflow exploit.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to read about the GNU assembler, or GAS. You can also put assembly code in-line in C code.

Comment: I don't think your first instruction is a valid one on x86 chipsets. Have you thought of downloading Intel's own *very* detailed Processor Manuals? It contains descriptions of all mnemonics and their parameters, and their hex notation as well.

Comment: It's supposed to be a movl....got it compiled. Thanks

Comment: I've posted an answer but I have one more question, please refer to below... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Compiled with gcc -m32 -c code.s

Output was a file code.o

I used objdump -d code.o > code.asm to obtain the raw assembly and bytes needed.

Output:

```
code.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   c7 05 00 d2 04 08 86    movl   $0x1a4bb386,0x804d200
   7:   b3 4b 1a
   a:   68 5f 91 04 08          push   $0x804915f
   f:   c3                      ret
```

I'm curious what the instruction does at VA 0x7 ... Is that just the rest of the instruction movl?

Comment: It's not a separate instruction.  You have two bytes for the instruction, 0xc7, 0x05; four bytes for an address in little endian format, then 4 more bytes of another little endian address.  For some strange reason, the assembly listing only shows 7 bytes maximum per line.